# Upgraded to newer Firefox, addon was disabled, want to re-enable it

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

After upgrading to the newer Firefox, a useful addon was disabled (marked incompatible).

In my case I went up to Firefox 11.0, but now my beloved [Tab Utilities Lite 1.1.3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/) is obsolete.

Can I do anything to make it work again in this version of Firefox which has marked it incompatible and disabled it for me? Or should I hope that the addon is upgraded to the next version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [a comment](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/reviews/342443/) on the link you posted:

> I'm sorry. It will be available by this weekend. You may use 1.2pre18 for now. https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/versions/1.2pre18

So, there is [an experimental version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-utilities/versions/?page=1#version-1.2pre18) that works with Firefox 11.0, and an updated version is to follow.

Comment: Awesome it worked!  I owe you big time. Thank You Very, Very  Much!

Answer (score 4):

There's a way to enable incomparable addons in about:config. It might not work, but it's worth a shot: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-install-or-force-enable-incompatible-add-ons-in-firefox-4-beta/